# Declaring a 10 item array as Dim items(10) As String. Any disadvantages?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, performance, memory

For simplicity, in vb.net, I would like the first item in an array to be accessed by:

```
firstItem = items(1)
```

instead of

```
firstItem = items(0)
```

I realize that items(0) will be empty if I declare

```
Dim items(10) As String 'This reserves 11 spots in memory, not 10
```

for a 10 item array, but it will clear up a lot of confusion in my code.  Is there any significant disadvantage of doing this?  Are there any  performance disadvantages?

Comment: Simplicity of what?  When you do `items.Length` it'll say 11.  Do you want to have to put `-1` throughout your code?

Comment: I will not need to call the length for my program.  But that is something to take in to consideration.

Comment: Visual Basic declares arrays as `0 To 10`, meaning that it will create index 0-10 which is 11 items. In VB you gotta do `Dim items(10 - 1) As String` or `items(9)` to get 10 elements.

Comment: Use a `Collection` instead. I believe they're one-based.

Comment: Arrays in Visual Basic go from position 0 to n. Ignoring this in your code will only make thinks more complicated for any programmer who has to touch the code. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx

Comment: What is someone else has programmed it this way and I am  proofreading?  Is there an advantage changing the array to have 10 elements instead of 11?  And, not to mention, changing each index in the existing code...

Comment: @Visual Vincent - yes, a collection would be a great idea!  I'm really wondering about performance or any other disadvantages with existing code using the 11 item array (being used for 10 items)

Comment: See the question in my duplicate flag.

Comment: The question is similar, but not what I'm asking.  Is there any disadvantage, except having an empty space in memory (items(0))?

Comment: The disadvantage can come later when maintaining it and you're not sure if the 10 spots used are 0-9 or 1-10, or can't figure out why an array has been declared with 11 elements when only 10 are needed.

Comment: Stolen from a duplicate: "Good developers write code for others to read, so I commend you for considering how to make your code logical and understandable."

Comment: @Claudius thanks, your link answered my question!  I have accepted this as a duplicate question